# Rails server command fails when run with RAILS_ENV set as `production`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
root@a03d0f401acc:/build# RAILS_ENV=development rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.11.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[38] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[38] * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.4.9-p362), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[38] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[38] * Environment: development
[38] * Process workers: 2
[38] * Preloading application
[38] * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
[38] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[38] - Worker 0 (pid: 42) booted, phase: 0
[38] - Worker 1 (pid: 46) booted, phase: 0
^C[38] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
[38] === puma shutdown: 2020-03-17 18:12:45 +0000 ===
[38] - Goodbye!
Exiting
root@a03d0f401acc:/build# RAILS_ENV=production rails server
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

I don't understand why it's different when using a different environment? Also why it 'fails' when using `production`?

How can I investigate this issue further?

---

Attempting with the `-e production` parameter:

```
root@d1e8ba096718:/build# rails s -e production
Error: Command '-e' not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

---

This is the Dockerfile I'm using for the environment:

```
FROM ruby:2.4
# FROM ruby@sha256:7bda74910b6ef1c81b157e72de3f009d32c2a311b4d74a75483042d7ba441ee9

COPY dental /build
#COPY .bundle /root/.bundle

WORKDIR /build
RUN bundle update json || true #partial cache..

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libgmp3-dev
RUN cat /etc/os-release
RUN apt-get install -y ruby-full
RUN apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install openssl libssl-dev

RUN bundle update json puma rdoc

# RUN bundle update json
# RUN bundle install

RUN ls -altrh
RUN ls -altrh /root/.bundle
RUN cd ~; pwd
RUN pwd
COPY Gemfile /build/Gemfile

RUN bundle update rails

#CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
CMD ["sleep", "100000000"]
```

Comment: Have you tried `rails s -e production`

Comment: Just updated the question with the output.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more background, such as rails version and where you're trying to run the server? Is there anything different in your rails setup from what you might have done in the past with rails?

Comment: Check `which rails` to make sure you're running the correct executable. Then check what's in it. Some gems like to wrap `rails`.